How would I format a string value from a custom list into money format?
I know this is likely a duplicate question and for that I am sorry. I have been looking for a way to format a custom string, that is pulling values from SQL database. I have read many S.O. on formatting and none have worked.
Ideally I would want the string value to come out something close to $999,888,432.23 (this value is only a placeholder).
Below is one of the ways I have tried to get this string value formatted and I just don't understand why there was 0 changes.
The current string value output is something like 5921.1500000000 (for example; there are always 5-10 trailing 0 that I am trying to remove).
Please let me know if you need more information.
for (int i = 0; i < Sort_List.Count; i++)
{
    Sort_List[i].DollarsOpen = string.Format("{0:0.00}", Sort_List[i].DollarsOpen);
}

Update 1: The following is all the converted data types that is coming from the database. Originally DollarsOpen was a decimal
public class JTPosOpen
{
    public string PoDate;
    public string VendorNo;
    public string Vendor;
    public string PONumber;
    public string POLine;
    public string QtyOrdered;
    public string QtyReceived;
    public string QtyRemaining;
    public string UOM;
    public string ExpUnitCost;
    public string DollarsOpen;
    public string GLAcct;
    public string GLCtr;
    public string JobNo;
    public string ItemNo;
    public string Desc1;
    public string Desc2;
    public string RequestDate;
}


What is the data type of Sort_List[i].DollarsOpen?

@Primdonm: When you are asking question like this you should be more specific. What is you source data type? According to your code the Sort_List[i].DollarsOpen is the string format. Therefore, there is no sense to use numerical pattern like "{0:0.00}" in the Format convertion.

I think i have added the requested information.

Originally DollarsOpen was a decimal: You should have kept it as a  decimal. See Decimal.ToString Method, Standard numeric format strings, and Custom numeric format strings

If the value is a string, then you'll have to use string operations (such as String.SubString) to get the desired output. But you shouldn't do this. Store the value as the proper data type (ie: decimal).

The better data type to save currency is decimal.
Therefore, keep data as decimal and when it is necessary convert it to the string:
decimal price = 123456.4444m;
Sort_List[i].DollarsOpen = $"{price:C}";

The formatted value here will be "$123,456.44".

Perhaps you will need to specify the `CultureInfo` if the current culture in your environment uses the currency symbol different from the `$`:
Sort_List[i].DollarsOpen = price.ToString("C", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

